# Validate model instance from python using Django admin validators

Tags: python, django, validation

I'm working on the importing script that saves data from CSV to Django database. Saving process looks like this:

```
instance = ModelName(**kwargs)
instance.save()
# No errors reported
```

But when I try to edit and save some items using admin panel it shows me a message that some of the field values (like URL fields and custom validators) is not valid.

**Question**: Is there any way to validate model instance from the python code using Django admin validators?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is `save()` does not validate by default.

To address this, you can call the model's [`full_clean` method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.full_clean) to validate before calling `save`.
So, under the hood,

> This method calls Model.clean_fields(), Model.clean(), and
>   Model.validate_unique() (if validate_unique is True), in that order
>   and raises a ValidationError that has a message_dict attribute
>   containing errors from all three stages.

The code would look something like this:

```
instance = ModelName(**kwargs)
instance.full_clean() #Does validation here
instance.save()
```

Comment: That's a good idea but I also have custom validators in the admin panel. Also, some fields, for example, URLField will not be validated properly with `full_clean()` method.

Comment: Custom validators should be picked up too.. did you give this a try?